# Grouping words based on hierarchy in R

Tags: string, r, hierarchy

I would like to get a hierarchy in my vector of words like in the example:

```
# Start (in reality these will not be right next to each other)

words <- c("hello-world", "hello", "string", "sub-string", "custom-fields", 
           "custom", "hi-hat", "hat") 

# Result

highlevel <- c("hello-world", "sub-string", "custom-fields", "hi-hat")
lowerlevel <- c("hello", "string", "custom", "hat")
```

In reality I'll be facing big data and am looking for an efficient way to group these. If possible, I would also like them to be linked somehow. The goal is to search for the higher level words first, and when they are not found, look for the lower level words.

Ideas?

Comment: Are "high level" words defined as words with a dash? if so `grep('-', words, value=TRUE)`  `g=grep('-', words);hl=words[g];ll=words[-g]`.

Comment: In the current scenario I think either "-", "." (literally, not regexularly) or numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
g <- grep('[-.[:digit:]]', words) # give indices of matches.

highlevel <- words[g]
lowlevel <- words[-g]
```